# adding event to calendar dynamically

Tags: android, calendar

i developed a app something like appointment where user will enter some details along with date and time he wants. Then i want to display that appointment details in calendar for particular date and time that was selected by user.

i have used following link to add event to calendar. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976098/how-to-set-reminder-in-android/5976386#5976386)

In this i am adding all my details to ContentValues using put().Through this code i am able to add event to current date only since i am adding cal.getTimeInMillis().

how can add my appointment to particular date?
can anybody solve my issue?
please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set event to particular time by adding time in milliseconds.  Example use `cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000` instaed of `cal.getTimeInMillis()` to get any particular date

### Example

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but user will dynamically take his date, but how can we measure that date using cal.getTimeMillis()+60*60*1000.

Comment: you can get the date difference betwen user selected date and current date

Comment: thank you for response,to make my thought clear once again i am telling, (User will select particular date in date picker, for that date event should be added, cal.getTimeInMillis+60*60*1000 using how can we get user date? for suppose his date is 07/01/2011 mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: to make a Date object from a DatePicker you'd do new Date(datePicker.getYear() - 1900, datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth());

Comment: hey i got new one to convert our date& time into millis, epoch converter it is, so that we may pass converted form to put(). can u suggest to how can i use this?