# How to create/set remainder in Android application?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set reminder in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976098/how-to-set-reminder-in-android)

I want to make application which is create remainder. But I dont know hoe to set/create remainder? I want to know how to create remainder in Android? For more specific I want to make a text, audio, video remainder.

Can anyone help me? Please give the example so I can understood properly.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about a reminder? Maybe you should explain what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Hey sstn I updated my question. Can you give me the example for this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following links. That will help you to proceed further

[Setting a Reminder Alarm](http://androidgenuine.com/?tag=setting-a-reminderalarm-on-android)

[how-to-set-reminder-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976098/how-to-set-reminder-in-android)