# How to develop Reminder in my Android Application(1.6)?

Tags: android

i want to make reminder in my android application..i have taken date-picker and time-picker and stored the time and date in Sqlite database.now i want to compare those values from database of time n date with system date n time..i mean want to make reminder.(like birthday reminder)

So,how should i develop it...can anyone suggest me or give some sample code of the same..
thanks in Advance--

Comment: Refer to the answer given by user shadowcloud here. 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976098/how-to-set-reminder-in-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976098/how-to-set-reminder-in-android

Comment: @andro_selva i gone through that links...but occurring some like  failed to find provider info for calendar   when i use second ans. from second link....can you tell me..whats that error.exactly?

Comment: did u provide the permissions correctly

Comment: yes..i have provided read n write both permissions correctly...

Comment: do you have an google calendar installed and activated in your mobile. This cannot be checked in emulator though

Comment: @andro_Selva oops!!can you please guide me how to install it...and can i install it on simulator??

Comment: No you can't get the required output even if you install calendar in emulator. You must have a device to check this

Comment: okey....so how to install it..can you please tell me?

Answer (score 0):

[AnCal](http://code.google.com/p/ancal/) stores yours appointments, tasks and notes, which you can easily add and edit. You can also set alarms for selected items and see day, week and month reports of your appointments.

Comment: i am developing my own app..in that app i want to develop reminder(Like for birthday).

Answer (score 0):

You can start a pending intent using the Alarm Manager and the intent will be received by a BroadcastReceiver that should handle the event. If your phone is restarted you can start the application at boot time, read all the reminders from the DB and schedule pending intents for all.