# Crash Occur while running app in ICE CREAM SANDWICH

Tags: android

I have created an app that stores events in the device calendar, and it works. But when I try to do the same thing in ICE CREAM SANDWICH  it crashes the app. Why does this happen? Can anyone help me solve this? The code I have used to save events in the device calendar is shown below. The log for the crash is included also.

**Code for saving events to device calendar**

```
public boolean setAlertOnDevice(Context c)
{                   
Resources res = c.getResources();

Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/" + "events");

Uri REMINDERS_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/" + "reminders");

    ContentResolver cr = c.getContentResolver();

Date dtStartDate = getStartDate();  

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.setTime(dtStartDate);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, m_iStart);

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);  
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, DEFAULT_TIME_OF_DATE);     
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, DEFAULT_TIME_OF_DATE); 
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, DEFAULT_TIME_OF_DATE);

String str = m_reminderText + res.getString(R.string.alert_start);                                          
m_strDescription = res.getString(R.string.alert_start_msg);

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("calendar_id", 1);
values.put("title", str);
values.put("description", m_strDescription);                    
values.put("dtstart", cal.getTimeInMillis()); 
values.put("dtend", cal.getTimeInMillis()); 
values.put("hasAlarm", 1);
Uri event = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);

m_calendarEvents[m_calendarEventCount] = event;
m_calendarEventCount = m_calendarEventCount + 1;

values = new ContentValues();
values.put("event_id", Long.parseLong(event.getLastPathSegment()));
values.put("method", 1);
values.put("minutes", 10);
cr.insert(REMINDERS_URI, values);
}
```

**Log output**

```
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause          activity {in.plackal.lovecyclesfree/in.plackal.lovecyclesfree.ActivityManager}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Event values must include an eventTimezone
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2706)
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2662)
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2640)
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at  android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Event values must include an eventTimezone
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165)
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:415)
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:730)
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at in.plackal.lovecyclesfree.CycleManager.setAlertOnDevice(CycleManager.java:1083)
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at in.plackal.lovecyclesfree.ActivityManager.onPause(ActivityManager.java:83)
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:4563)
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1195)
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
03-02 18:28:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     ... 12 more
```

Comment: And this is why you don't use undocumented APIs. They might change at any point without further notice. Lucky for you, it's gotten replaced with an official API. See [this post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/ics-and-non-public-apis.html), Calendar section.

Comment: How can i solve this issues..Can u please explain me..

Comment: Alextsc...i have created my app using api level 8. So my question is whether this CalendarContract should work in my code

Answer (score 2):

I also meet this problem and now I solve it. The code you want to work fine above ICE CREAM SANDWICH ,you need to set the values of eventTimezone. Well , just need to add the code like

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("calendar_id", 1);
values.put("title", str);
values.put("description", m_strDescription);                    
values.put("dtstart", cal.getTimeInMillis()); 
values.put("dtend", cal.getTimeInMillis()); 
values.put("hasAlarm", 1);

values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());  //add this row

Uri event = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);
```

Answer (score 1):

alextsc is correct. You're using undocumented APIs here, which are unsupported and broken for Ice Cream Sandwich. Read that [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/ics-and-non-public-apis.html) he linked to, and then look into using the [CalendarContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html) API to make Ice Cream Sandwich work for you.

Comment: I go through but not able to understand...where i should get the api and how to implemented it in my code

Comment: I ma trying to use CalendarContract class in my code but it shows error..class not found

Comment: It's only for Ice Cream Sandwich. As they say in the blog post, you'll need to use [http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/backward-compatibility-for-android.html](reflection) or [http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html](lazy loading) to figure out which code to use in your app. You'll choose your old code for older versions, and the CalendarContract for Ice Cream Sandwich.

Comment: The link you have provide doesn't open..can u please check this out

Comment: The tags are broken for some reason. Weird.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/backward-compatibility-for-android.html

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html