# how to set reminder?

Tags: android

in my application I got the date and time via DatePicker and TimePicker and set reminder on Perticular user selected Date and Time, But I already done Date and Time Picker but don't know how to set reminder on that, Kindly help me.Thanks

Comment: Use alarm manager for remainder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example

Comment: duplicate question....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976098/how-to-set-reminder-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Set an Alarm using AlarmManager, or create a Calendar event using the Calendar Provider API.