# Sync custom calendar with Android & iOS

Tags: android, iphone, ios

My boss ask me to create a website where they have a calendar and they can manage their travel agenda. This part is done and working well.

However, now, I did some researches and I did not really get answer to my question...

I am trying to find **How to sync my calendar website with an Android OS and iOS (native calendar app) ?**

- Is there a sort of API or custom command wihtin both OS ?
- Would I need to write my own application ?
- What do you suggest ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to create your own app on iOS and Android, because maybe in the future you want to add more functionality to it that the native calendar doesn't support. So for iOS there is an example on [developer.apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) that will show you how to access and use most of the calendar features.

On android, you can find more examples on how to use the calendar, on [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) or on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976098/how-to-set-a-reminder-in-android/5976386#5976386)

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. I think I'll just develop an application for the company itself with multiple fonctionnalites because the calendar is only one part but I wanted to have it wihtout installing application.

Comment: Yes ... I forgive you ! Hehe ... I'll still try, I found CalDAV but it's not that easy ... the amount of work required would be similar to developping two simple app I think.

Comment: If you pay well I will create your iOS and Android apps ;))