# Add event and multiple reminder to that event in calender app

Tags: android, events, calendar

I want to add an event to calender with different reminder time 7 days before and 1 hour before the start time

Here is what i am doing

```
long timeInMilliseconds = 0;
            String date = selectedEvent.eventDate;
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date mDate = null;
            try {
                mDate = sdf.parse(date);
                timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
                System.out.println("Date in milli :: " + timeInMilliseconds);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(mDate);
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
            intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
            // intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
            cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
            intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
            intent.putExtra("title", selectedEvent.name);
            String body = "";
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Log.d("", "Timzone--" + format.getTimeZone());
            Date convertedDate = new Date();
            try {
                convertedDate = format.parse(selectedEvent.eventDate);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            outputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());


            body += outputFormat.format(convertedDate) + "\n";
            body += selectedEvent.name + "\n";
            body += selectedEvent.format + "\n";
            body += selectedEvent.remark1 + "\n";
            body += selectedEvent.remark2 + "\n";
            body.replaceAll("null", "");
            intent.putExtra("description", body);
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, plat);
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Can anyone tell me how to add reminder

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an event to a calendar, you should call the Calendar app with the values set. Since you want to add two events, you have to call the Calendar app twice and set different values to both.

Code to add event to Calender

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, date());
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, false);
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title[i]);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

Now since you want to add two reminders, call this method twice with different parameters for date at `intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, date());`

Comment: sorry i posted wrong question i want to add reminders in a event

Comment: @Android try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719696/how-to-set-multiple-reminders-in-android

Comment: this doesnt meet my requirement i want user to see the pre filled calender app and change accordingly