# Is there any way to add multiple reminders for the same event in android?

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to add multiple reminders for the same event in android (I need it before 4 hours, 3 hours, 2 hours, 1 hour)) Hope you guys can help me..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you should be more specific, where do you want multiple reminders? In the callendar app?

You should take a look at this : 
[Add event and multiple reminder to that event in calender app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34152522/add-event-and-multiple-reminder-to-that-event-in-calender-app)

[how to set multiple reminders in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719696/how-to-set-multiple-reminders-in-android?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Yes in Calendar app..Thanx @Vascote, Let me try this

Comment: Is is possible without using Intent..?Actually I don't want user interaction in this task.

Comment: @JIThi with ContentValue maybe, look at the second link.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using alarm manager then here is code

```
    // context variable contains your `Context`
AlarmManager mgrAlarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentArray = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
   // Loop counter `i` is used as a `requestCode`
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, i, intent, 0);
   // Single alarms in 1, 2, ..., 10 minutes (in `i` minutes)
   mgrAlarm.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60000 * i, 
                pendingIntent); 

   intentArray.add(pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: Thanx @Dhara Patel for your time